# Counting names in a excel cell that may contain multiple answers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Good Morning

I need your help with a formula please, I have a list of items in one cell:

| Column A |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Banana |
| Pear |
| Grape |
| Apple / Banana |
| Grape / Pear / Apple |

I would like the result to say:

```
Apples 3
Banana 3
Pear   2
Grape  2
```

I have done the following =countif(Range, list) this counts all the individual items, but it won't count the items when included with other items.

Can you help please?

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: You can use wildcards with `COUNTIF()` however depending on your data this could be sensitive to false positives.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include wanted results, it's hard to read from a comment. FYI: [wildcards](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-wildcard-characters-in-searches-ef94362e-9999-4350-ad74-4d2371110adb)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option to include all unique items from your list and their count without the possibility of false positives:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(x,A1:A6,y,DROP(REDUCE(0,x,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,," / ")))),1),z,MAP(y,LAMBDA(c,SUM(--(c=y)))),UNIQUE(HSTACK(y,z)))
```

You can include `SORT()` to nest `UNIQUE(HSTACK(y,z))` in if need be sorted on count and/or type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **TEXTSPLIT** function to split the single column into multiple columns using the forward slash as a delimiter.

Surround the formula in the **TRIM** function to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
=TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/",,TRUE))
```

Then use the **COUNTIFS** function to count the results.

```
=COUNTIFS($B$1:$D$7,"="&B12)
```

[image]

Comment: I have Office 365 and I don't have the `TextSplit()` worksheet function. I don't know if the author has this problem too, but can you mention what you need (to do) in order to access that function?

Comment: If you have a subscription, you can use the web version of Excel.  It will have the FUNCTION available.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, I have now figured it put with the help of JvdV.

=countif(A2:A6,"*Apple*")

I have added a star before and after the word Apple but its not showing in the formula

Result Apple 3

The only downside is I have to amend each cell with the word Apple or Banana etc but I am happy with this.

Ta